# SQL Find next order date for each row in an Orders table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an orders table. Each order has a date and a customer_id attached to it.

I am trying to identify how many instances there are where a customer has a gap of more than 365 days between orders.

My solution is as follows, to left join the orders table to itself to identify the next order for a user; however, this runs incredibly slowly and feels very inefficient:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT
    transactions.customer_id,
    transactions.transaction_date,
    DATEDIFF(day, transactions.transaction_date, MIN(next_transactions.transaction_date)) days_to_next_transaction
  FROM (
    SELECT
      customer_id,
      transaction_date
    FROM
      transactions_table
  ) transactions
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      customer_id,
      transaction_date
    FROM
      transactions_table
  ) next_transactions
  ON
    transactions.customer_id = next_transactions.customer_id AND
    transactions.transaction_date < next_transactions.transaction_date;
)
WHERE
  days_to_next_transaction > 365
```

Theoretically, I feel like I could sort my list of orders by `customer_id` and then `transaction_date`. From here I would only have to make one pass of all of the rows: I would compare one row to the row immediately beneath it - if the next row shares the same customer_id as my current row, I will calculate the days to the next transaction as the difference between the date in the next column - the current one.

Is there any way of implementing this?

Comment: Just as you described: take a look at the `LAG` function, create a new column as "previous_transaction_date".  When that is built, use it in a subquery to diff the two transaction dates.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much!